# Does cytoscape support multiple ports for a single node?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Cytoscape provides a configuration for a single source/target endpoint, but can it support N endpoints? (I couldn't find any source for that in the documentation or in google, meaning that the answer might be negative, but I want to make sure before I decide to go for a different solution)

illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but in a limited way.
To do that, you need to use bezier edges (https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/bezier-edges).
The two useful options here are: "control-point-step-size" and "control-point-distance" (choose one of them)

Then, just define your edges and they won't overlap

```js
 var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
          container: document.getElementById('cy'),

         layout: {
            name: 'preset',
         },
            
          style: [
            {
              selector: 'node',
              css: {
                'shape': 'rectangle',
                'width' : '280',
                'height': '35',
                'border-style' : 'solid',
                'border-width' : '1',
                'background-color': 'white' ,
                'border-color':'black',
                'color': 'white'
              }
            },
            {
              selector: 'edge',
              css: {
                'width': 1,
                'target-arrow-color': 'black',
                        'line-color': 'black',
                'curve-style': 'bezier',
                'control-point-distance':50
              }
            },
            
          ],
            elements: 
            [
                { data: { 'id': 'node1' }, classes: '', position: { x: 25, y: 120 }  }, 
                { data: { 'id': 'node2' }, classes: '', position: { x: 10, y: 500 }  },
                { data: { 'id': 'node3' }, classes: '', position: { x: 200, y: 350 }  },

                {"data":{"source":"node1","target":"node2"}, "group":"edges", "classes":""},
                {"data":{"source":"node2","target":"node3"}, "group":"edges", "classes":""},
                {"data":{"source":"node1","target":"node2"}, "group":"edges", "classes":""},
                {"data":{"source":"node1","target":"node3"}, "group":"edges", "classes":""},
                {"data":{"source":"node1","target":"node2"}, "group":"edges", "classes":""},
                {"data":{"source":"node3","target":"node2"}, "group":"edges", "classes":""},
  
            ]
        });
```

```css
#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.12/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but I'm failing to see the connection to my question. I'm trying to have 2 source ports in one node - don't care about overlapping edges and don't see why the edge type should matter (either way, I'm using an unbundled-bezier curve already)

Comment: I don't think there's a property to do exactly what you are looking for. But if you look closely at the example and move the nodes a bit, you'll see that it has different endpoints (but calculated automatically). I was talking about overlapping edges and bezier edges because when you don't specify bezier edges, nodes have only 1 endpoint and so, they overlap... And so it works. But it's difficult to answer without really knowing what you want to achieve

Comment: Playing with "control-point-step-size" or "control-point-distance" is the key in my opinion (maybe even edge-distances but never tried it). Let me know if you find any better solution if you're not ok with this

Comment: This is actually a side effect and not a solution. The reason this works is because the edges are calculated from the center of the node.
What I require is control over the ports - I need to control N (the number of ports) and I need to control which edge goes to which port

Comment: @Ofir I was evaluating cytoscape for a similar use case. Were you able to find a solution for this? I was thinking of using compound nodes, so having a compound node which contains a rectangular node with a label and then N "port nodes" on one side and have edges go to the ports... not sure if you tried such approach and checked what kind of results you'd get...

Comment: @GACy20, I eventually opted to write my own graph since I couldn't find a solution and my use case was pretty simple

Comment: @Ofir Yes, my use case is simple too.. but it requires port. I'll probably use something like react-xarrows, so that I can write the nodes as plain react components. The layout in my case should be very simple since I have few nodes and mostly in layers, and I will just draw the arrows...

Comment: @GACy20 I did it in Vue but with the same approach (nodes are elements, edges are drawn in SVG behind)

Comment: @GACy20, I made similar thing as you suggested - put multiple nodes inside compound node (with grabbable set to false, to not allow moving them inside compound)  but there is not possibility to set size of compound node and set position of ports inside the compound node. Compound node always surrounds equally child nodes (ports), and I don't know how to move them on left or right side of compound node. Maybe you can advice something?